# CSS: adjusting position of 4 images in a div

Tags: css, image, html, position

I have this problem: I cut a circle in 4 pieces in Photoshop and I wanted to use them as 4 links in an HTML page. SO I created a DIV like this:

```
<div id="box"> 

    <a href="www.abc.com"><img src="G.png" /></a>
    <a href="www.efg.net"><img src="UW.png" /></a>

    <a href="www.yahoo.com"><img src="DW.png" /></a>
    <a href="www.google.com"><img src="R.png" /></a>
</div>
```

and a CSS file like this:

```
#box {
    width:185px;
}
```

but the result isn't what I want. As you see in the picture, there is a space between these 4 images. How can I fix this problem? Thank you.
http://www.img4up.com/up2/96145115384598309149.png

Comment: Do you use some `CSS reset` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
img { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

a { float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the padding and margins to 0?

`#box a, #box img{margin:0px; padding:0px;}`

Comment: Yes and it didn't work and I have to say, I found the answer. But thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It's whitespace and line-height (whitespace is honored between inline and inline-block elements).  There's quite a few ways to eliminate it, but this one is my favorite:

```
<img /><!--
--><img />
```

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

You can eliminate the spacing caused by line-height like this:

```
line-height: 1;
```